# Difference in use between predefined typeclasses and basic types

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I am reading through some of the examples in LYAH and I came across this snippet of code:

```
replicate' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
  | n <= 0    = []  
  | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

This is from the online version, but I also have a copy of the book which has this instead:

```
replicate' :: Int -> a -> [a]  
replicate' n x  
  | n <= 0    = []  
  | otherwise = x:replicate' (n-1) x
```

I have tried both of these out and they both work but my question is:

Are these implementations different and when should I use the typeclasses instead of the regular types?

Comment: `(Num, Ord)` is too weak to ensure sane behavior. It should probably demand `Integral` instead.

Comment: @dfeuer: To elaborate, if you're working with `Set`s of complex numbers, you need an instance `Ord a => Ord (Complex a)` (arguably, this is a design flaw in `Set`) and then the question "What does `replicate (0 :+ 1) foo` mean?" rears its head. The law `concat . replicate a . replicate b === replicate (a*b)` is going to be broken, I think!

Comment: @yatima2975, the existence of the inherently-broken instances `Num Double` and `Ord Double` is another concern. One could also, I think, imagine a type expressing ideas related to non-standard analysis (with infinitesimals) that could be bad for `replicate` even if perfectly sane.

Answer (score 2):

The second version only works with an `Int` as the first parameter. The first version is more general and works with any type in the `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses. The `Num` typeclass defines basic operations used with numerical types. In this case, `replicate'` needs to be able to subtract 1 from the parameter `n`. `Ord` defines comparison operations. This is needed since you use `<=`. Note that `Int` is in both of these typeclasses and so it supports both of the required operations. By declaring the function with more a more general type signature, `replicate'` can be used with any other type which supports the required operations.

Comment: Correct answer. Worth adding, though: GHC *might* generate better code for the version with the narrower type declaration—in *some cases*.  (Don't go hardcoding any functions to use `Int` without benchmarking!)